# Count Off Rows in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I want to count off rows in a table. I want it to dynamically assign an arbitrary value to the record so I can group on that value in Visual Studio 2010.

So my data set would look like this:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╗
║ BinID ║ CountOffID ║
╠═══════╬════════════╣
║ A1    ║          1 ║
║ A2    ║          2 ║
║ A3    ║          3 ║
║ A4    ║          1 ║
║ A5    ║          2 ║
║ A6    ║          3 ║
║ A7    ║          1 ║
╚═══════╩════════════╝
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Also, a simple CASE WHEN does not work as 3 is not evenly divisible by 10.

Comment: You're probably going to need to be more specific about what you mean by *dynamically assign an arbitrary value*

Comment: I just want the number to start at 1 and go to 3. It has no value aside from my grouping. I want it to always start with the first record and go to the last record in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with NTILE here is that it will [partition the numbers in sequence](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db784/7/0).

If you really want to assign the number in a count off fashion, you can do the following.

```
With CTE as (

SELECT 
   BinID,   
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BINID) rn
FROM 
  Table1)
SELECT
  BinId,
  CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 0  then 3 
       ELSE rn % 3
  END as CountOffID 
From cte
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db784/5)

This creates a rownumber and then uses [modulo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) to generate the number.

If you could ensure that there were no gaps you go do it directly off of the BinID but you'd need to parse and convert which seems fragile.

Comment: Thank you Conrad, I tried Lamak's solution to no avail, and had started to look for other options. I found yours to work rather well. I have a couple of minor bugs in the beginning, but worked them out rapidly. Thank you for your help, it was much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT BinID, 
       CountOffID = NTILE(3) OVER(ORDER BY BinID)
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I guess I do not understand the syntax here. Can I ask for an explanation?

Comment: @Jake Sure. The `CountOffID = ` part is just another way of assigning an alias to the column, it's the same as `AS CountOffID`.  [NTILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) is one of the many ranking functions available in SQL Server 2005+